# Teamcity CI/incremental builds - Change log

Tags: version-control, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

We are running TeamCity Enterprise 7.0.4 (build 21474)

We have teamcity CI/incremental builds running every 15 minutes or so.
The incremental builds identify the VCS activity, checkout the new/modified code, and run a build.

We need this CI build to trigger another teamcity project. The triggered project needs information about the VCS changes that were checked out and built by the CI project.

To be specific we need VCS author(s) user id(s), their email id(s), and the file(s) modified
Seems this info can be obtained via Change Log/Pending Changes from teamcity

Any pointers, how to pass this info to the triggered project

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using snapshot dependencies. What is the VCS you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on what you want:
* Show changes from first project in changes log of second project (TeamCity UI only)
  Set snapshot dependency.
* Changes list inside build step as data for some process (writing into changelog.txt or something similar)
  Use TeamCity Rest API to obtain such information.
  Use query "/app/rest/changes?locator=build:(id:BUILD_NUMER_HERE)" to get build changes.
  Build number could be obtained by empty artifact dependency or snapshot dependency.
  If there a dependency, you can address parameters of first build as %dep.btxxx.build.number%

More documentation:
[About dependencies](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Dependent+Build)
[About Rest Api](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API)
[About parameters from dependencies](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-DependenciesProperties)